# VS code and virtual environment issues

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, virtualenv

I am trying to run a code in vs code in virtual env (python=3.9). and I have a question:

Just recently, the env that I used to work with this code all the time, does not recognize the python packages. I reinstalled the packages and the issue is not solved. I created a new env and installed the packages, but it is the same. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance,

I searched for the issues and it seemed reinstalling keras helps, but it didn't for me.

Comment: Did you try using somthing like https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/  pipenv for virtual enviroment

Comment: if you are having a trouble with vscode consider using pycharm just to check if the code will work or not it and install what is needed

Comment: I find that sometimes in VSCode, if my system went into hibernation/sleep mode and I return, the terminal sessions for my open workspace will no longer have the venv activated, and I need to manually reactivate, or close and reopen the workspace. Because VSCode just runs the script in the terminal, if the terminal is not activated for the venv, then it won't be able to find the packages as it will be running on the base install instead of the venv packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks you all for your responses. I do not use virtualenv so I did not try that. That issue had happened because I had installed Xcode. I uninstalled it, and reinstalled vscode and created a new env and installed all the packages and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look in the lower righthand corner to check what version of Python you are using, you can also use `cmd+P`(Mac) or `ctrl+P`(Windows) and type `>` to pull up developer options